# cannot change menu background color

Tags: android, background-color, android-toolbar

I have a problem with a background color of my action menu items. As you can see below I tried to set the same background color as for the toolbar. But they are still different. I use different attributes -- `background` and `itemBackground` -- but they both don't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:itemBackground= "@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey">

    <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
        android:id="@+id/mainMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"
        android:itemBackground= "@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And this is my menu.xml file where I also tried to set color:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MyActivity"
    android:background = "@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:background = "@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey"
        android:itemBackground= "@color/BackgroundToolbarGrey">

    </item>
</menu>
```

I also tried to set it programmatically, but it doesn't help

```
mainMenu= (ActionMenuView) findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
mainMenu.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BackgroundToolbarGrey));
```

What can I do wrong?

Comment: have you bind menu item ?

Comment: yes, thank you, I posted additionally my menu.xml file

Comment: What about doing this through the themes.xml file?

Comment: @Eenvincible, I would like to find a way to set in without theme

Comment: means you want same color in both `Toolbar` and `ActionMenuView`?

Comment: yes: "As you can see below I tried to set the same background color as for the toolbar"

Comment: if you want same color in all than `toolbar` `background` is enough. no need to set in `ActionMenuView`, `Menu` and `MenuItem`

Comment: As you can see, I used 3 methods to set the color instead of one and none of them helped me.

Comment: can you post screenshot and color code?

Answer (score 0):

You should set a PopupTheme for your ActionMenuView.

java code

```java
  mActionMenuView = (ActionMenuView) findViewById(R.id.action_menu_view);
  mActionMenuView.setPopupTheme(R.style.OverFlowMenuTheme);
```

style.xml

```xml
  <style name="OverFlowMenuTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
      <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/white</item>
      <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
      <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: You should include some comments in your answer and an explanation of your code sample.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the menu item's properties in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Something like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        View mainMenu =  menu.findViewById(R.id.mainMenu);
        mainMenu.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.BackgroundToolbarGrey));    
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Menu doesn't have a findViewById() method.